# XCode 5 постоянно падает

Tags: xcode, macos

Надоедливая проблема падения среды разработки XCode доводит до чёртиков. Стоит XCode 5, падает, когда ему вздумается без видимой причины, не сохраняя, конечно же, недавно написанный код.

Это решение не помогает:
[Xcode 5 crashes — Xcode quit unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905900/xcode-5-crashes-xcode-quit-unexpectedly)

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не поможет, xCode всегда падал и будет падать!
Купите AppCode и сохраните свою жизнь!

Answer (score 0):

Поставить xCode 6?

Comment: xCode 6 Сегодня меня выбесил своей наивысочайшей тупостью и крахами... Советую установить его ради SDK.

Comment: Пятый падал стабильно раз в неделю, 6й тоже самое, открыт всегда, по несколько больших проектов, все норм, работать можно. Может у вас Mac доисторический или хакинтош? )))

Comment: Вот чем дольше я сижу на маках, тем сильнее хочется купить хакинтош на зеонах. Эпловская маркетинговая принудительная обнова, мне не подуше. Я хочу обновлять iMac не потому-что новая Ось стала с прозрачным блуром и моя тачка его не тащит, а потому что я хочу чтоб функций он больше выполнял. А что косается топика, то да.. я заметил если свернуть xCode в док, то он действительно недельку то держится не падает  ^_^

Comment: @Bimawa у меня всегда открыт и работает, периодически, правда, загружает проц на 200%, если верить Activity Monitor, но тем не менее

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовала всё, что мне предложили, и, как ни удивительно, единственное, что помогло, - работать в AppCode и забить на XCode совсем.

Comment: Да еслиб не AppCode, в топку программировать под iOS. :)

Answer (score 0):

может падать из-за "запутанности" папок кодом ; была такая проблема

Answer (score -1):

Решить очень просто. Переставьте наново, предварительно потерев все, что связано с XCode.

Comment: Не помогло

Answer (score -1):

Ну поделитесь хоть бэктрейсом. А пока:

1. Проверить обновления в App Store.
2. Проверить кол-во свобоной памяти.
3. Открываем Terminal.app и `mv Library/Developer{,_bkp}`
4. В терминале sudo `rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app` после этого устанавливаем заново из AppStore

После каждого из пунктов проверяем работоспособность.